# cannot get to run Modal view in bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have this example from bootstrap site:

Launch demo modal

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-header">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
<h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal header</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
<p>One fine body…</p>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
<button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
</div>
</div>
```

Inside the  I have this line:

```
<link href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Before the  tag ends i have placed these two lines:

```
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/bootstrap/assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

It stucks on open the modal view, it just makes the background highlight with black and nothing shows up :s, What I am doing wrong? Any idea?

Comment: "for questions about twitter bootstrap, please use twitter-bootstrap tag" might be needed here, because it definitely doesn't sound to be about how-computer-gets-ready-to-operate-at-boot-time.

Answer (score 0):

You've take the post JS outputted HTML from bootstrap documentation rather than the required pre rendered HTML.

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    <h3>Modal header</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>One fine body…</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <a href="#" class="btn">Close</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</a>
  </div>
```